# Serving static content with Struts2: Tomcat error 404

Tags: tomcat, static, struts2, web-applications

With Struts2 I can't find a way to serve a static CSS :-/ Newbie question but I could not find any answer on the Internet:

The CSS file is `static/styles.css` in my WAR file.

Tomcat replies with 404 when I request `http://server/myapp/static/styles.css`

But it works if I put `styles.css` at the root of the WAR and request `http://server/myapp/styles.css`

I tried adding the following to my `struts.xml` in the only package but still 404:

```
<action name="/static/*">
  <result>/static/{1}</result>
</action>
```

Or as a second package:

```
<package name="static" extends="struts-default" namespace="/static">
  <action name="/static/*">
    <result>/static/{1}</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

Comment: Is your Struts2 dispatcher set to /* ? Did you read this? http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/static-content.html

Comment: I had read this page, yes. The first paragraph explains how static content is enabled by default. The 2nd paragraph explains how to write my own loader (not needed). The 3rd paragraph explains that my code should work. The 4th paragraph explains how to prevent serving (not needed). Summary: my code should work, according to this page. This page does not talk about "/*" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very old question, but since it wasn't answered and I was struggling with the same problem, I'm sure others might benefit from a solution.

Struts serves static content by default from JARs only, but not from subdirectories outside the JARs. So you need to add this to your struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value=".*/static/.*" />
```

That prevents anything in the "static" folder from being handled as an action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include anything (action or package). Struts2 serves static content by default.

Check if after deploying your war file, the resource style.css exists in the path you think.